# How to set WinHTTP Proxy using a PAC File?

Tags: windows, proxy

Is it possible to set the WinHTTP proxy using a PAC file? Currently, our org sets the following registry key to point to a PAC file... can this be used for WinHTTP as well? If so, what commands are needed?

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"AutoConfigURL" = URL TO PAC FILE
```

Thanks in advance for the help.